# jquery regex replace() only runs twice... then doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I ashamed and frustrated by this question. I'm writing what should be a pretty simple script that removes "y"s and replaces them with "i"s. When this happens, I add a  with a class to the new "i" so that I can undo it. For some reason, the first replacement works... the switch back works... it works AGAIN... then stops. I don't know what else to do but just post the whole ugly script.

Don't worry about the gnarly regex expression (it's targeting only certain "y"s which are sometimes used for writing Mohawk).

EDIT: Here's a live version on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkVBk/

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

    function swap_out_y(x) {
        //alert(x);
        x = x.replace(/y/, "i");
        x = x.replace(/Y/, "I");
        alert('swap_out_y just ran. x = '+x);
        return x;   
    }

    function swap_out_i(x) {
        //alert(x);
        x = x.replace(/i/, "y");
        x = x.replace(/I/, "Y");
        alert('swap_out_i just ran. x = '+x);
        return x;   
    }

    $('body').delegate('.y_to_i', 'click', y_to_i);
    //$('body').delegate('.i_to_y', 'click', i_to_y);

    function y_to_i() {

        $("span.mohawk_word").each(
            function() {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).text().replace(/(y[aevu])|(y[oe]n)/ig, function(s) {
                        return '<span class="consonant">'+swap_out_y(s)+'</span>'; 
                        })
                );
            }
        );



        $('.y_to_i').undelegate('click');       
        $('.y_to_i').addClass('i_to_y');
        $('.y_to_i').removeClass('y_to_i');
        $('body').delegate('.i_to_y', 'click', i_to_y);
        //alert('A');
    } //end y_to_i


    function i_to_y(){

        $("span.consonant").each(
            function() {
                $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/i/ig, 
                    function(s) {
                        return swap_out_i(s);
                    }
                )//replace...
                );//html
                //$(this).removeClass('replacement_i');
            }//function(){
        );//each(   

        $('.i_to_y').undelegate('click');
        $('.i_to_y').addClass('y_to_i');
        $('.i_to_y').removeClass('i_to_y');
        $('body').delegate('.y_to_i', 'click', y_to_i);
    }

} //function
); //document ready
```

Comment: Not your problem, but you'll want to add the `g` flag to the end of all your regular expressions, otherwise they'll only replace the first instance.

Comment: Can you provide a live example with http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Change `x = x.replace(/i/, "y");` to `x = x.replace(/i/g, "y");` etc. - Also you sample code is too big.

Comment: Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkVBk/

Comment: I didn't add the /g flag because there should never be more than on y in that search match. The main regex is globalized because it needs to match multiple words on the page, but the second one only test for upper or lower case "y"/"i".

Comment: As they say, "You've got a problem and you want to solve it with regular expression.. Well now you've got two problems."  Just needed to have your second function target the same span as your first instead of continually embedding new spans. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling delegate on 'body' and then calling undelegate on some classes instead of body.  So you're ending up with multiple delegates.

Working fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/5HdSC/1/

Answer (score 0):

you forgot your span in your i_to_y function so it has no span  $("span.mohawk_word") to iterate through after you have removed and replaced it twice with consonate, it is gone.

**Edit**
Actually you already have the span in your html so you don't need to add additional spans in your returns... Just make the other function also use the mohawk_word span
replacing with mohawk_word spans throughout fixes the problem.

```
        function y_to_i() {

        $("span.mohawk_word").each(
            function() {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).text().replace(/(y[aevu])|(y[oe]n)/ig, function(s) {
                        return swap_out_y(s); 
                        })
                );
            }
        );



        $('.y_to_i').undelegate('click');        
        $('.y_to_i').addClass('i_to_y');
        $('.y_to_i').removeClass('y_to_i');
        $('body').delegate('.i_to_y', 'click', i_to_y);
        //alert('A');
    } //end y_to_i


    function i_to_y(){

        $("span.mohawk_word").each(
            function() {
                $(this).html(
                    $(this).text().replace(/i/ig, 
                    function(s) {
                        return swap_out_i(s); 
                    }
                ) );                  
            }
        );

        $('.i_to_y').undelegate('click');
        $('.i_to_y').addClass('y_to_i');
        $('.i_to_y').removeClass('i_to_y');
        $('body').delegate('.y_to_i', 'click', y_to_i);
    }

}
```